# Regex to extract four digits using Java Pattern

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to extract four digits before the file extension using Java Pattern Matchers. It's throwing no group found exception. Can someone help me on this ?

```
String fileName = "20210101-000000_first_second_1234.csv";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\\\d{4}");
System.out.println(pattern.matcher(fileName).group(4));
```

I would like to get `1234` from the fileName. I compiled the file pattern using regex `\\\\d{4}`. Which returns four groups. So, fourth group should suppose to return `1234` which is not returning, instead throwing group not found exception.

Comment: Have you tried a utility that'll let you do testing without compiling, like https://regex101.com/?

Comment: That looks like two backslashes too many.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `"\\\\d{4}"` string literal defines a `\\d{4}` regex that matches a `\dddd` string (a backslash and then four `d` chars). You try to access Group 4, but there is no capturing group defined in your regex. Besides, you can't access match groups before actually running the matcher with `Matcher#find` or `Matcher#matches`.

You can use

```java
String fileName = "20210101-000000_first_second_1234.csv";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{4}(?=\\.[^.]+$)");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(fileName);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/8goDvy) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EN4ems/1). *Details*:

- `\d{4}` - four digits
- `(?=\.[^.]+$)` - a positive lookahead that requires a `.` char and then  one or more chars other than `.` till end of string.

Note also the `Matcher m = pattern.matcher(fileName)` added and `if (m.find())` checks if there is a match. Only if there is a match, the value can be retrieved from the 0th group, `m.group()`.